# Material Switch Component that toggles back automatically or a better solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn React JavaScript and now I have this problem

I have this [Material Switch Component](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/) that I was using to toggle new theme among 8 themes. I'm a beginner and see now that my usage of the `Switch` was not the best.

Basically what I did was like this to toggle Themes:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import ThemeContext from '../../../theme/ThemeProvider';

export default function ThemeSwitcherComponent() {
    const { setThemeType, themeName } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const handleSwitch = () => {
        setThemeType();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <FormControlLabel
                labelPlacement="bottom"
                label={themeName}
                control={<Switch disabled={false} onChange={handleSwitch} />}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

Nothing special here just a `context` that handles set Theme.
Here is all Themes:

```
const allThemes = [
    { name: 'Sage', theme: Sage },
    { name: 'Hero', theme: Hero },
    { name: 'Explorer', theme: Explorer },
    { name: 'Caregiver', theme: Caregiver },
    { name: 'Creator', theme: Creator },
    { name: 'Innocent', theme: Innocent },
    { name: 'Jester', theme: Jester },
    { name: 'Lover', theme: Lover },
    { name: 'Magician', theme: Magician },
    { name: 'Everyperson', theme: Everyperson },
    { name: 'Revolutionary', theme: Revolutionary },
    { name: 'Ruler', theme: Ruler },
];
```

Here is an image of the `Switch`:

[image]

I made a [movie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlWWVuZAfzlCTQVw3veu__AOA809l6Un/view?usp=sharing) showing what it looks like, sorry a bit slow when I toggle Theme like 5-6 sec delay. What I want is not a drop down list to do this I want a simple button/Switch click

And it works ok it's just that the toggle it not meant to be used like this because initially the toggle is OFF and show Theme nr1, like a blue color theme, then I toggle the `Switch` and it then is ON and show Theme nr2 that is Pink color theme. And then again I toggle OFF for nex Theme and it's stupid to do like this I think.

I tried this to when I toggle the `Switch` on it set the next Theme and then the `Switch` is toggled OFF, and ready for new toggle ON.

```
export default function ThemeSwitcherComponent() {
    const { setThemeType, themeName } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const [switsh, setSwitch] = useState(false);

    const handleSwitch = () => {
        setThemeType();
        setSwitch(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <FormControlLabel
                labelPlacement="bottom"
                label={themeName}
                control={<Switch disabled={false} onChange={handleSwitch} checked={switsh} />}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

I feel this got to be a no no so I ask this question for some help

I have looked in Material UI Component and can't find a suitable Component to do this better and would like som input how to do this better.

Comment: Is the idea that upon toggling the `Switch` control it would select a random theme from that list? Then switch back to the "default" theme when it is toggled off?

Comment: I don't know if I understand, but isn't better to use the select component, where you can select the theme that you want? https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

Comment: I made a [movie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlWWVuZAfzlCTQVw3veu__AOA809l6Un/view?usp=sharing) showing what it looks like, sorry a bit slow when I toggle Theme like 5-6 sec delay. What I want is not a drop down list to do this I want a simple button/Switch click. But a button feels so not intuitive to do this